# Signal Comparison method

Tags: python, matlab

I have 2  raw signals  having same sampling rate and they start at different time. I am interested in trying to do a match making(i.e. both to be similar without any deviations) of these signals in python 3.5. Can anyone give me inputs on what is the best method to compare such signals and say there is no change in pattern?

Answer (score 0):

I'd find the moment with peak amplitude in both signal stream, and sync the signals there. Then I'd go over the signal, sample by sample, normalize the values based on the peak amplitude and compare the trend.

I don't think this question should be here, by the way, try to ask in a more relevant StackExchange forum.

Answer (score 0):

What i can recommend is:

1. **Fast-Fourier-Transform**: you get all the different frequencies within your two signals and then you can see if there are any different peaks between the two spectrum of the signals.
2. **Wavelet Transform**: kind of same working principle of the *FFT* but you will be using a 'Wavelet' to analyse your signal instead of a sinusoid in the *FFT* then you can then compare the energy of your signal's details
3. **cross-correlation**
4. **Statistical tests** calculate the standard deviation of a signal and then test if the values of your other signal are still within the range of 2 or 3 *sigma*.

Is it possible to have a sample of these two signals?

Comment: Well its huge samples of data. Finally i have those samples stored in the form of an Array. To be more clear, These are same Signal data taken from different Simulation runs. I should also automate the process of comparison in this case.

Comment: Just try to go with the propositions above, do some research and come back if you still habe any questions. To automate the process, you should define a Threshold to say when your signals will be different,etc....